# PHP update password form not working

Tags: php, forms, post, pdo

I'm trying to make a form for users to change their password.

```
              <div class="panel panel-primary">
                 <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo $errormessage;?></h3>
                 </div>
                 <div class="panel-body">
                    <form method="post" name="passwordchange" id="passwordchange">
                       <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3"><label>Password</label></div>
                                <div class="col-md-5"><input class="form-control" name="pass1" id="pass1" type="text" required value=""></div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3"><label>Confirm Password</label></div>
                                <div class="col-md-5"><input class="form-control" name="pass2" id="pass2" type="text" required value=""></div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="submit" value="submit">
                       </div>
                    </form>
                 </div>
              </div>
```

```
    <?php
$ok=true;
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$new_password = $_POST['pass1'];
$new_password2 = $_POST['pass2'];

$userid=$_SESSION['user']['id']; 

if($new_password!=$new_password2){
    $ok=false;
    $errormessage="Passwords do not match.";
}

if($ok){

$errormessage="ok";
$salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
$password = hash('sha256', $new_password . $salt); 
for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
   { 
   $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
   } 



   $query = "
   update users
   set
   password = :password,
   hash = :hash
   WHERE id = '$userid'"; 

       // The parameter values 
   $query_params = array( 
   ':password' => $password, 
   ':salt' => $salt
       ); 

   try 
   { 
           // Execute the query against the database 
       $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
       $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
   } 
   catch(PDOException $ex) 
   { 

       //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
       die("update error");

   }
header("Location: account.php?success");

}

}

?>
```

When I submit the form the page reloads and nothing happens. When I enter two different passwords I get the error message 'Passwords do not match.'

I also get a weird behavior when the form reloads, the navigation on my site stops working after the form reload.

I tried playing with the input type name, form name, using isset _request instead of isset _POST. But nothing seems to help.

What did I do wrong?

**edit:I mixed up SALT and HASH. Wooops..**

Comment: Error reporting and display errors on?

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure you [don't escape passwords](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79668/login-with-password-hash) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You're not outputting any valuable error messages.

Comment: I'm trying with error logs on now. What could cause the weird navigation / refresh error?

Comment: @Enrico most likely the `die()` is hit because of the below answer, thus leaving the HTML or Javascript of your site incomplete.  Look at the HTML source, not the browser rendering.  If you weren't catching that Exception and doing nothing with it, then PHP would display the exception letting you know what is wrong.  It's a bad practice to suppress errors or exceptions during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query you have hash and password, in the prepare SALT and password. There is no salt in your query.

Comment: God damnit.. You are right. I mixed up salt and hash. I didn't even notice it :/

Answer (score -1):

Basically, in your if condition equals to true not going to inside if condition.

Try this

if ($ok == 'true') {

}

Comment: While `true == 'true'` works because of loose comparisons in PHP, this has no effect on the above code and would be a bad practice to compare a boolean to a string.